# Unity without using Update

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I'm developing a small game currently that involves players guessing. The player can additionally use special cards, that, for example, reveal one letter/add time he/she has for guessing and so on. Game is divided into two scenes -> one with shop, inventory, player profile etc the second one is strictly for guessing.
Currently, almost everything runs in the update in the second scene, but I really hate it. I was trying to rewrite everything into coroutines BUT the problem is that it seems impossible to use cards inside IEnumerator (or maybe I'm doing something wrong?).
For example, a simple countdown. If it's in Update I can easily influence the time with using cards(f.e. add 30 seconds). In the case of IEnumetor, I can't (Or maybe better, I don't know how to do it).

```
int secondsForGuess = 30;

 IEnumerator Countdown () {
     int counter = secondsForGuess;
     while (counter > 0) {
         yield return new WaitForSeconds (1);
         counter--;
     }
 }
```

Any general suggestion how to do it without using Update will be greatly appreciated :D

Comment: could you add more code for context? Where and how do you start the Coroutine?

Comment: Why don't you want to use update? You can use the `Datetime.Now` for checking the time without using too much resources. Set an initial time in the start and then check if the difference of time in the update exceeds the time limit you have given.

Comment: if you `yield return null;` you continue execution the next frame. i dont get what your problem with update is though.

Comment: I'm afraid that the game will use too much resources in case I will do everything in the Update :) Basically my first Android game.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question right, you want to be able to increase the counter from the outside of the routine. So simply make it a field in the class so anyone can increase or decrease it:

```
const int secondsForGuess = 30;
private int counter;

public void AddToCounter(int seconds)
{
    counter += seconds;
}

private IEnumerator Countdown () 
{
     counter = secondsForGuess;
     while (counter > 0) {
         yield return new WaitForSeconds (1);
         counter--;
     }

     // Do something when finsihed
 }
```

Also just in case: Make sure to somewhere start the routine using [`StartCoroutine`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html).

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted to do, will definitely check it out. Thank you for a great suggestion!